# C# Renci SshNet The server response contains a null character at position 0x0000002A

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, openssh

i have multiple Raspberries running with SSH server:
(OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019).
And if i try to connect via Renci SshNet, i get the following error message:

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: "The server response
> contains a null character at position 0x0000002A:
>
> 00000000  53 53 48 2D 32 2E 30 2D 4F 70 65 6E 53 53 48 5F
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_   00000010  37 2E 34 70 31 20 52 61 73 70 62 69 61 6E
> 2D 31  7.4p1 Raspbian-1   00000020  30 2B 64 65 62 39 75 37 0A 00
> 0+deb9u7..
>
> A server must not send a null character before the Protocol Version
> Exchange is complete.
>
> More information is available here:
> [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-4.2%22)

```
SshClient scClient = new SshClient("123.123.123.123", "pi", "raspberry");
scClient.Connect();
```

is it possible to change the behavior of the ssh server,
or even better; can i tell renci ssh to ignore these protocol errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem of the latest SSH.NET NuGet Package. Currently the newest is `2020.0.0`. And the one prior to that is `2020.0.0-beta1`.

`2020.0.0` gives me this problem, `2020.0.0-beta1` does not.

I will report this issue on https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues

**EDIT:**

`2020.0.1` just got published. That doesn't seem to have this problem. I recommend you to try that version.